# Setting index of item in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following code which inverts `IP_TABLE` to give `FP_TABLE`.

```
IP_TABLE = [58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2, 60, 52, 44, 36, 28, 20, 12, 4, 62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6, 64, 56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9, 1, 59, 51, 43, 35, 27, 19, 11, 3, 61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13, 5, 63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7]
FP_TABLE = [0]*64
for n in range(64):
    FP_TABLE[IP_TABLE[n]-1] = n+1
```

This works fine, but is it possible to use a list comprehension? I wasn't sure how to do it because the index depends on the value of the item.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "invert"?

Comment: The 58th item in `FP_TABLE` will be 1, the 50th item will be 2, the 42nd item will be 3 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it, though it seems very inefficient:

```
[IP_TABLE.index(n+1)+1 for n in range(64)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do it more efficiently, you should resort to numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
IP_TABLE = np.array(IP_TABLE)
FP_TABLE = np.arange(1,65)[np.argsort(IP_TABLE)]
```

Compared with @Scott's answer:

```py
#%%timeit
[IP_TABLE.index(n+1)+1 for n in range(64)]
#> 54.2 µs ± 17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

#%%timeit
np.arange(1,65)[np.argsort(IP_TABLE)]
#> 17 µs ± 4.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**3 times faster!**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While it's more efficient I'd prefer not to use additional libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It could be written a little differently, but your solution is already more efficient than a list comprehension that searches each element sequentially.

```
IP_TABLE = [58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2, 60, 52, 44, 36, 28, 20, 12, 4, 62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6, 64, 56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9, 1, 59, 51, 43, 35, 27, 19, 11, 3, 61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13, 5, 63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7]

FP_TABLE = [0]*len(IP_TABLE)
for i,p in enumerate(IP_TABLE,1):
    FP_TABLE[p-1] = i

print(FP_TABLE)
[40, 8, 48, 16, 56, 24, 64, 32, 39, 7, 47, 15, 55, 23, 63, 31, 38, 6, 46, 14, 54, 22, 62, 30, 37, 5, 45, 13, 53, 21, 61, 29, 36, 4, 44, 12, 52, 20, 60, 28, 35, 3, 43, 11, 51, 19, 59, 27, 34, 2, 42, 10, 50, 18, 58, 26, 33, 1, 41, 9, 49, 17, 57, 25]
```